# rxjs: how to replace each element of array

Tags: typescript, rxjs

How to simplify this code?
I want the method to return instances of `TorrentFile`

```
getFiles(id: string): Observable<TorrentFile[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<ITorrentFile[]>(
            `${ this.resourceUrl }/${ id }/files`,
        )
        .pipe(map(
            (items: ITorrentFile[]) => {
                const data: UserTorrent[] = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    items[ i ] = new TorrentFile(items[ i ]);
                }
                return items;
            })
        );
}
```

The `TorrentFile` class ans interface looks like this:

```
export interface ITorrentFile {
    name: string;
    length: number;
    bytesCompleted: number;
}

export class TorrentFile implements ITorrentFile {
    public name = '';
    public length = 0;
    public bytesCompleted = 0;

    constructor(object: ITorrentFile) {
        return Object.assign(this, object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is much you can simplify, but here's what comes to mind:

```js
getFiles(id: string): Observable<TorrentFile[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<ITorrentFile[]>(
            `${ this.resourceUrl }/${ id }/files`,
        )
        .pipe(map(
            (items: ITorrentFile[]) => items.map(item => new TorrentFile(item)))
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already quite clean, I'll only simplify the looping with `map`

```
getFiles(id: string): Observable<TorrentFile[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<ITorrentFile[]>(
            `${ this.resourceUrl }/${ id }/files`,
        )
        .pipe(map((items: ITorrentFile[]) =>items.map(item=>new TorrentFile(item)))
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, too:

```
    .pipe(map(items => items.map(item => new TorrentFile(item))));
```